# Integration of a differential form

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds

Let $\omega$ be a $2$-form on $\mathbb{R}^3-\{(1,0,0),(-1,0,0)\}$,
$$\omega=((x-1)^2+y^2+z^2)^{-3/2}((x-1)dy\wedge dz+ydz\wedge dx+zdx \wedge dy)+
  ((x+1)^2+y^2+z^2)^{-3/2}((x+1)dy\wedge dz+ydz\wedge dx+zdx \wedge dy)$$ 
and $S=\{(x,y,z)\in \mathbb{R^3}: x^2+y^2+z^2=5 \}$.

In this condition, we calculate $\int_{S}\omega$, where the orientation of $S$ is the natural orientation induced by $D=\{(x,y,z)\in \mathbb{R^3}: x^2+y^2+z^2 \leq 5 \}$.

I can't calculate this, so if you  solve this, please teach me the answer for this.

Comment: The $\omega$ you give is a 1-form. Then the integral makes no sense. Probably a typo? Also, what did you try already? The formulation of the exercise is screaming for Stoke's theorem.

Comment: Sorry,I correct it then.

Comment: Hint: Use polar coordinates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\omega_\pm = ((x\mp 1)^2 + y^2 + z^2)^{-3/2} ( (x \mp 1)dy \wedge dz + ydz\wedge dx + z dx \wedge dy)$.

Now $\omega_\pm$ is defined on $\mathbb R^3 - \{ (\pm 1,0,0)\}$ and $\omega = \omega_+ + \omega_-$.
Using polar coordinates centered at $(\pm 1,0,0)$: 
$$x = r \sin \theta \cos \phi \pm 1 \\ y = r \sin \theta \sin \phi \\ z = r\cos \theta$$
we can now calculate
$$\omega_\pm = \sin\theta \;d\theta\wedge d\phi.$$
 Since $d\omega_\pm = 0$ we have by Stokes theorem, that $$\int_S \omega  + \int_{-S_+} \omega_+ + \int_{-S_-} \omega_- = 0$$
where $S_\pm = \{(x,y,z) \in \mathbb R^3 \;|\; (x \mp 1)^2 + y^2 + z^2 = \epsilon\}$, thus

$$\int_s \omega = 2\int_0^{2\pi}\int_o^\pi \sin\theta \;d\theta \wedge d\phi = 8\pi.$$

Answer (score 0):

This is a closed form, i.e. $d \omega = 0$. Since the orientation of $S = \partial D$ is induced by the orientation of $D$, by Stoke's theorem
$$ \int_S \omega = \int_D d \omega = 0. $$
I leave checking that $d \omega = 0$ up to you.

Comment: "Let $\omega$ be a $2$-form on $\mathbb R^3 - \{ (1,0,0), (-1,0,0)\}$"

Comment: Yes, so what's the problem?

Comment: Stokes is not applicable.

Comment: Can you elaborate? By definition $\int_S \omega = \int \iota^* \omega$, where $\iota : S \to \mathbf{R}^3 - \{(1,0,0),(-1,0,0)\}$ is the inclusion map. We can think of $\iota^* \omega$ as first restricting $\omega$ to $D$, and then restricting further to $S$. Where is the flaw in this?

Comment: The boundary of $D - \{ (1,0,0), (-1,0,0) \}$ is not $S$. Actually $D - \{ (1,0,0), (-1,0,0) \}$ is not even a manifold.

Comment: The problem is that $\omega$ has two singularities. We can isolate them using Stokes theorem though. This leaves us with two integrals around those singularities.

Comment: Ah, I see. Thanks.

Comment: @AlexanderThumm: Dear Alexander, I realize that it's not relevant to your point, with which I agree, but I just wanted to clarify that $D - \{(1,0,0),(-1,0,0)\}$ is a manifold (with boundary).  Regards,

Comment: @MattE: Yes, you are absolutely right. I am probably so used to thinking compact manifold, that I have missed clarifying. So the correct statement would be $\omega$ does not have compact support on $D - \{ (\pm 1,0,0)\}$.  Thank you for pointing out my mistake. Regards